# get the input text field value on tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

Get the input text field value on tool-tip.for me I am using text-box with autocomplete..when ever i selected in autocomplete it will show in text-box. when i hover it i want tool-tip the value in text-box..how to get that one can anyone can help me

```html
<input type="text" value="something" class="curate">
```

Comment: Can you please show more code? you are being very evasive which doesn't help.

Basically what you want is when you change ($('input.curate').change()) you want it to change something in tooltip too.

Comment: Is the tooltip the native tooltip, provided via the `title` attribute, or is it provided by a plugin that you're using?

Comment: Actually i am  not using drop-down..its a auto-complete.change() function it will work

Answer (score 4):

Use the title attribute and pass the value of the input into the it on the keyup event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#testInput').keyup(function(){
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).val())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type Something
<input type="text" title="" value="" id="testInput">
```

Answer (score 1):

The first, you set the title is the value,
and do the same when you change the value of textbox

```js
function updateTitle(me)
{
me.title=me.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" title="something" value="something" id="one" class="curate" onchange="updateTitle(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input.curate').on('change', function (){
  this.title = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="one" value="something"  class="curate">
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("one");
x.title=x.value;
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..in my scenario id is auto-generated

Comment: Is the value autogenrated too if yes then you can manually add title tag to input element with that auto generated value as the the value of the title tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can using on hover to all inputs in you html like that :

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="number"],input[type="date"]').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).val()); });
```

Comment: I think you need to close the curly brackets in each of 'input[type="text"...'